# How to know if a notification from FCM not reach the target device?

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know if a notification from FCM reach a target device or not, so I can send an sms instead. How can I do that?
I'm building a cross OS app with react native, and I'm using FCM to send notification, but there is a problem, if the device is not online, the notification will not reach it. There is constraint in time, so I want to send an sms instead. Is there any approach for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase admin APIs and SDK gives you the analytical tools present in firebase console itself in `Reports Tab` and also the ability to extract and export the message delivery data in BigQuery to further use it. Once you get the data, you can process it as per your use case.

You can further study about the message delivery stuff [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery).